# $h(x) := \int f(x -t)g(t)\,dt,$ finite almost everywhere?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $C \in (0, 1)$ and $g(x) = |x|^{-C}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is nonnnegative, real-valued, and integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $$h(x) := \int f(x -t)g(t)\,dt,$$does it follow that $h$ is finite almost everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we have the convolution inequality  $(1\leq p \leq \infty)$
$$\|f\star g\|_p \leq \|f\|_1 \|g\|_p,$$
we only need $p=1$ here which is just from a direct calculation 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left |\int_\mathbb{R} f(x-y)g(y) dy\right| dx \leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_1.$$

Now given any compact interval $[a,b]$, the above implies $h\in L^1([a,b])$, since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}), g\in L^1([a,b])$ and we have
$$\int_a^b |h| \leq \int_a^b \int_\mathbb{R} |g(y)f(x-y)|dydx \leq \int_a^b |g|\int_\mathbb{R} |f|$$
 This implies $h$ is finite a.e.